# CSS color for consecutive paragraphs

Tags: html, css

Contained within a parent element (e.g., div, ul), I would like to set the color of a single paragraph, then have all subsequent paragraphs receive the same color -- until a new class of paragraph comes along to change the color.  I tried to implement selectors to get the job done, but the mixed results only ended up confusing me.  Suggestions would be appreciated.  Thank you.

```
<html>

<head>
<style>
p.r { color: red; }
p.g { color: green; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p class="r">RED
<p class="g">GREEN
<p class="r">RED
    <p>red
<p class="g">GREEN
    <p>green
<p class="r">RED
    <p>red
    <p>red
<p class="g">GREEN
    <p>green
    <p>green
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the style on the parent class ie.

HTML

```
<div class="parentdiv">
    <p>this will appear blue</p>
    <p>this will also appear blue</p>
    <p class="green">this will appear green</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.parentdiv p {
    color: blue;    
}
.parentdiv .green {
    color: green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not a very scalable solution, but one option is to repeat the adjacent sibling combinator and `p:not([class])` for as many consecutive `<class>` + `<classless>` elements there are in a row:

```css
p.r,
p.r+p:not([class]),
p.r+p:not([class])+p:not([class])
{
  color: red;
}

p.g,
p.g+p:not([class]),
p.g+p:not([class])+p:not([class])
{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<p class="r">RED</p>
<p class="g">GREEN</p>
<p class="r">RED</p>
<p>red</p>
<p class="g">GREEN</p>
<p>green</p>
<p class="r">RED</p>
<p>red</p>
<p>red</p>
<p class="g">GREEN</p>
<p>green</p>
<p>green</p>
```